# Can you reload JBoss ESB services via an MBean or something similar?

Tags: java, jboss, esb, system-properties

The services defined in my jboss-esb.xml refer to properties from the SystemProperties service.

When I change a property in the properties file (ie, /conf/my-props.properties) I can reload them using the SystemProperties MBean.  I am unsure, however, how to get the services to reload using the new properties without redeploying the esb archive or without deploying the archive exploded and 'touching' the jboss-esb.xml.

Is there a way that I can trigger the esb to reload the services via an MBean or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're already using Spring, but since probably you are, you might want to give a try to **ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource**. I can give you more details about this if you find this to be a viable solution.

Comment: Thanks but in this example I was using Seam....No Spring in sight.  Also it was over a year ago now and I'm long gone from that place of employment ;)  Thanks anyway